# Android returning false for 1 == 1, what on earth is happening?

Tags: android, debugging, android-debug

[image]

As can be seen in the image above I test if integers 'count' and 'done' are the same and if they are true is returned. However this is returning false when they are both 1. This code is called in Volley's onPostExecute method. Strangely after returning false sometimes the if statement calling this method acts as if true has been returned. When not debugging it seems to run as intended. This isn't making much sense to me so any ideas would be appreciated. Could it just be a debugger glitch or is there a deeper problem that needs addressing?

Comment: Yeah, it's just the debugger.

Comment: Try to remove the comment, insert a line before if... Sometimes the source is wrongly compiled, the compilers have bugs too...